# Cannot validate mimetype for a missing file

Tags: cakephp, upload, cakephp-3.0

```
    <?php
        public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
        {

             $validator->add('image', [
                'uploadError' => [
                    'rule' => 'uploadError',         
                    'message' => __d('Message', 'The logo upload failed.'),
                    'last' => true
                ],
                'mimeType' => [
                    'rule' => array('mimeType', array('image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg')),
                    'message' => __d('Message', 'Please upload images only (gif, png, jpg).')
                ],
                'fileSize' => [
                    'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '1MB'),
                    'message' => __d('Message', 'Logo image must be less than 1MB.')
                ],
            ])
            ->allowEmpty('image');
```

The above validation code got the error..

```
            $validator
                ->requirePresence('owner', 'create')
                ->notEmpty('owner');
            return $validator;
        }
    }
    ?>


Whats wrong with my validation code? when i comment the validation in image field it will save into database.,
```

[image]

But when i dont comment, it will always said "Cannot validate mimetype for a missing file"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
'image' => array(
    'uploadError' => array(
        'rule' => 'uploadError',         
        'message' => __d('Message', 'The logo upload failed.'),
        'last' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => true
    ),
    'mimeType' => (
        'rule' => array('mimeType', array('image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg')),
        'message' => __d('Message', 'Please upload images only (gif, png, jpg).'),
        'allowEmpty' => true
    ),
    'fileSize' => (
        'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '1MB'),
        'message' => __d('Message', 'Logo image must be less than 1MB.'),
        'allowEmpty' => true
    ),
)
```

You can use also use `extension` rule for validating file type like below:

```
'image' =>array(
    'extension' => array(               
        'rule' => array('extension',array('gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'),
        'message' => __d('Message', 'Please upload images only (gif, png, jpg).')
    )
),
```

Comment: $validator->add('image',               I add your code after this code but their is an error

Comment: use  `var $validate = array(my_code);` 
Also put `var $actsAs = array('Multivalidatable');` in model class

Comment: please see my update code including your code...   using the link below https://gist.github.com/distromob/

Answer (score 0):

MY guess is one of the rules is throwing an exception (likely to be `mimeType`) because of error in upload process.many php level configurations control $_FILES array population, one such setting is upload_max_filesize. As a result any file function which depend on file availablity will not work properly.

#### whats wrong with my validation code ?

Nothing. This is the intended behavior, all validation rules are being run no matter if a previous one failed. So in your case, an upload error will be recognized, but validation will still proceed to the next rule, which is then going to fail hard as no file has been uploaded.

This behavior can be disabled by using the last option. Marking a rule as last will cause validation for that field to stop in case the rule fails.

```
  'uploadError' => [
  'rule' => 'uploadError',
 'message' => __d('clients', 'The logo upload failed.'),
 'last' => true
 ],
```